# manifest Class-Path not honored in a Wildfly module

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-11, jboss-modules

I'm trying to create a Wildfly Module for OpenText Documentum java client. Previously I was packing its jars to the .war file and my app was working, but they weight 23Mb.

In J2SE you usually just add the main jar which is `dfc.jar` and its dependencies are automatically added, because of `Class-Path:` entry in `dfc.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. However, it doesn't seem to work in Wildfly 11: I created the module, made my webapp depend on it, but when I try to load the `DfException` class from the main jar Wildfly fails to find one of the dependencies which are in the same folder:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
    at com.documentum.fc.common.DfException.<clinit>(DfException.java:710)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.foo.PrintClassloaders.printClassloader0(PrintClassloaders.java:50)
```

**Is it possible to create this module without adding all the jars by hand?**

Here's what I did:

```
module add --name=documentum.dfc2 --absolute-resources="C:\Program Files\Documentum\Shared\dfc.jar"
```

src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Dependencies: documentum.dfc2
```

PrintClassloaders.java:

```
Class.forName("com.documentum.fc.common.DfException");
```

generated module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="documentum.dfc2">    
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="C:\Program Files\Documentum\Shared\dfc.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

dfc.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Class-Path: All-MB.jar activation.jar aspectjrt.jar certj.jar commons-
 codec-1.3.jar commons-lang-2.4.jar configservice-api.jar configservic
 e-impl.jar cryptoj.jar cryptojce.jar cryptojcommon.jar dms-client-api
 .jar jaxb-api.jar jaxb-impl.jar jcifs-krb5-1.3.1.jar jcm.jar jcmFIPS.
 jar jcmandroidfips.jar jsr173_api.jar krbutil.jar log4j.jar questFixF
 orJDK7.jar util.jar vsj-license.jar vsj-standard-3.3.jar xtrim-api.ja
 r xtrim-server.jar
```

`aspectjrt.jar` is in the same folder. Why isn't it picked by the module classloader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, to add all the dependent jar files from the manifest Class-Path you have to explicitly create a `<resource-root>` element for each jar.

For cases when there is too many jars or there's a deep hierarchy I made a tool that parses the manifests recursively and prints the `jboss-cli` command to create the desired module.

```
Example:
  C:\> java -cp org.foo.modulegen.Modulegen C:\some\main-jar.jar
Output:
  --absolute-resources="C:\some\main-jar.jar;C:\some\jar2.jar;..."
```

https://gist.github.com/basinilya/15db9267ec753941d098cfd2f7ff844d

The tool tries to open each command line argument as a `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`, finds and parses `MANIFEST.MF` with `java.util.jar.Manifest` and then does the same for each entry in the `Class-Path` attribute. It also ensures to not open the same jar file twice.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying there looks very strange to me. Modules (=Java libraries) belong into the modules folder and deployments should contain a deployment descriptor which lists all modules that it needs. In easiest case you only need the dependencies section inside the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file. See http://docs.wildfly.org/12/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file

Each module can contain multiple jar files and depend on other modules. When you take a look into some existing modules.xml files, you will see how it goes. Path names inside module.xml should be relative, otherwise you are not able to deploy them onto another computer with different folder structure.

You do not need any Manifest file for this.

Comment: You don't understand. Paths can be absolute since Wildfly 10. I know there can be multiple jars in a module, I just don't want to add them manually, because this info is already in the manifest file

Comment: I wrote you what Wildfly provides. It does not use the manifest file, regardless how much you wish